# How to avoid yum searching rpms in subdirectories of the artifactory baseurl

Tags: artifactory, rpm, yum, repo

I have following repo configured

```
[Artifactory]
name=Artifactory
baseurl=http://myartifactory/artifactory/yum-local/repos/dev/$releasever/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

The above configuration searches rpms in `http://myartifactory/artifactory/yum-local/repos/dev/7Server/x86_64/` as well as `http://myartifactory/artifactory/yum-local/repos/dev/7Server/x86_64/subdir`

How can I force yum to only look at x86_64 and not its subdir?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the "RPM Metadata Folder Depth" settings in the RPM repository.This option will informs Artifactory under which level of directory to search for RPMs and save the repodata directory.
For example, if your RPMs are stored under 'fedora/linux/$releasever/$basearch', specify a depth of 4.

**Below link for more details:**
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/RPM+Repositories#RPMRepositories-LocalRepositories

Comment: Thanks @JayanthSuresh, I couldn't find any instructions to set this up though

Comment: @dganesh2002 - You can find this configuration in the UI in the repository configuration page. You can find more information on that here - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/RPM+Repositories#RPMRepositories-LocalRepositories